# Why does lag occur at these conditions?

Tags: audio, lag, queue

I was about to post something on tumblr. There was an online video playing on a second monitor. When the tumblr form for uploading a picture appeared, the sound of the video started lagging and sort of slowing down. Why does this happen? Does the answer involve the concept of queues?

- Windows 8 64 bits
- AMD E2-2000 APU 1.75 Ghz
- 4gb RAM

Video being played on full screen: http://oyc.yale.edu/philosophy/phil-176/lecture-23

Chrome Version 30.0.1599.101 m
Tabs opened

- Evernote dashboard
- Evernote note on a pop-up
- Tumblr dashboard with the form for publishing new post
- 1 or 2 more simple websites

Comment: *"a video playing"* -- What is the source of the video? HDD or DVD? Web/internet?  *"low RAM is the principal suspect"* -- I'm inclined to disagree.  What are the system specs>

Comment: Your question is extremely vague, and without providing detailed steps on how to reproduce the problem, answers would be opinions at best. Try rewording your question to include steps to reproduce, the particular video that was playing, your operating system, Chrome version, system specs, and even a screenshot of task manager / activity monitor at the time of the incident.

Comment: It's a web stream http://oyc.yale.edu/philosophy/phil-176/lecture-23
System specs are 

Proc: AMD E2-2000 APU 1.75 Ghz (64 bits)
4gb RAM

Comment: What's your ISP connection?  Insufficient ISP or network bandwidth is possible.  Try to replicate the problem using two PCs instead of multiple tabs on one PC.  Insufficient I/O or CPU bandwidth on your PC is very possible.  Playback of video can be notorious for being susceptible to glitches while multitasking. Integrated graphics and two monitors?  You're probably pushing that PC to its limits.